# jruby pass jvm arguments to rake task

Tags: jvm, rake, jruby

How do i pass jvm arguments like Xmx to a rake task in jruby?
Am using rvm and running the rake task "rake db:migrate".

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!

```
jruby -J-Xmx2048m -S /home/prats/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1@myapp/bin/rake db:migrate
```

Comment: You might also try `\`which rake\`` instead of specifying the full path for rake to make it a bit more general purpose.

Answer (score 7):

Rather that put the entire path, if jruby is already the Ruby you're using (for example, with rvm) such that just typing `rake` would be using jruby, you can use a double dash to send the arguments to the jvm.

Examples:

`bundle exec rake -- -J-Xmx1024m` (if you're using bundler)

`rake -- -J-Xmx1024m`